# Not able to get a value from formcontrol angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, form-control

I am trying to get a value from a angular formgroup.

When i use `formControlName` i can able to get the value but when i use `[formControl]` i am not able to read the value.

I am using [formControl] since i need to have autocomplete for the input field. Here is my code

**HTML**:

```
  <form class="form-horizontal" novalidate autocomplete="off" (ngSubmit)="searchTransaction()" [formGroup]="searchForm">

  <mat-form-field *ngIf="searchForm.get('searchType').value==2" class="example-full-width">
            <input matInput placeholder="Integrated Client"  [formControl] = "Client"  [matAutocomplete]="auto">
            <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
                <mat-option *ngFor="let option of clientfilteredOptions | async" [value]="option">
                  {{option}}
                </mat-option>
              </mat-autocomplete>                  
        </mat-form-field>
```

**Typescript**:

```
export class TransactionSearchComponent implements OnInit{
constructor(private fb:FormBuilder,private transactionService:TransactionService, private LoginvalidationService:LoginvalidationService, private ExcelService:ExcelService){   }
searchForm:FormGroup;
Client = new FormControl();

ngOnInit(): void {

        this.searchForm=this.fb.group({
                     client:[''],
                 })

       this.clientfilteredOptions = this.Client.valueChanges
        .pipe(
        startWith(''),
        map(value => this._Clientsfilter(value))      
      );
    }
 private _Clientsfilter(value: string): string[] {
        const filterValue = value.toLowerCase();  

        return this.clients.filter(option => option.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue));
    }

  searchTransaction(){ 
console.log(this.searchForm.get('client').value);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case, you need to add the `formControl` into `fromGroup`

There are two ways,

```
this.searchForm=this.fb.group({
    client:this.client
})
```

Or you can add the control in method. For Eg :

```
searchTransaction(){ 
    this.searchForm.addControl('client',this.client);
    console.log(this.searchForm.value);
}
```

*And better you keep either same cases (lowercase | uppercase | any preferred cases) which not confuse you when you write a long code*

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest instead of using *ngIf while working with form group use ngStyle or ngClass or [hidden] with property binding.

*** Reason behind forControlName not work with *ngIf - ngIf completely removes or adds block from html that's why variable not accessible outside of ngIf.***

Below is the working code with formControlName with hidden attribute,

**app.component.html**

```
<button (click)="toggle()"> Toggle LastName of FormControl </button>

<div >
  <form [formGroup]="fieldFormGroup">
    <input type="text" formControlName="firstName" /> <br /><br />
  <input type="text" formControlName="lastName" [hidden]="showBlock" /> 
  </form>
</div>

<div>
   {{fieldFormGroup.value | json}}
</div>
```

or

```
<input type="text" formControlName="lastName" [style.display]="showBlock ? 'inherit' : 'none'" />
```

or

```
<style>
    .hide {
        display: none;
    }

    .show {
        display: block;
    }
</style>
<input type="text" formControlName="lastName" [ngClass]="showBlock ? 'show' : 'hide'" />
```

**app.component.ts**

import { Component } from "@angular/core";

```
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder } from "@angular/forms";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  public showBlock: boolean = true;
  public fieldFormGroup: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.fieldFormGroup = this.fb.group({
      firstName: ["pravin"],
      lastName: ["patil"]
    });
  }

  public toggle() {
    this.showBlock = !this.showBlock;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to define the form control like this:

```
Client = new FormControl();
```

just use:

```
this.searchForm=this.fb.group({
                 client:[''],
             })
this.searchForm.controls.get("client").valueChanges.subscribe((value)=>{
      //Do something
});
```

and for the view use:

```
formControlName="client" // small one
```

Comment: Replace `this.form` with `this.searchForm` Lil typo

Answer (score 0):

Please check the capitalisation in html `Client` vs usage `client`

Comment: No even after changing the capitalization it did not work